# boost::spirit::qi and boost::phoenix::push_back

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

Based on a QA on [Using boost::spirit::qi and boost::phoenix::push_back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290389/is-there-an-alternative-for-boostphoenixat-c-in-combination-with-boostspir), the following code works fine - compiled with C++14.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

typedef std::vector<unsigned int> uint_vector_t;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const uint_vector_t &data)
{
    for (unsigned int i(0); i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        out << data[i] << '\n';
    }
    return out;
}

struct MyStruct
{
    uint_vector_t m_aList;
    uint_vector_t m_bList;
};


template<typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
struct MyParser : public boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator,
        MyStruct(),Skipper>
{
    MyParser() :
        MyParser::base_type(Parser, "Parser")
    {
        using boost::spirit::qi::uint_;
        using boost::spirit::qi::_val;
        using boost::spirit::qi::_1;

        using boost::phoenix::at_c;
        using boost::phoenix::push_back;
        using boost::phoenix::bind;

        aParser = "a=" >> uint_;
        bParser = "b=" >> uint_;

        Parser =
           *(  aParser [push_back(bind(&MyStruct::m_aList, _val), _1)]
            |  bParser [push_back(bind(&MyStruct::m_bList, _val), _1)]
            );
    }
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, MyStruct(), Skipper> Parser;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, unsigned int(), Skipper> aParser, bParser;
};

int main()
{
    using boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse;

    std::string input("a=0\nb=7531\na=2\na=3\nb=246\n");
    std::string::const_iterator begin = input.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = input.end();
    MyParser<std::string::const_iterator, qi::space_type> parser;

    MyStruct result;
    bool succes = qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, parser,qi::space,result);
    assert(succes);

    std::cout << "===A===\n" <<result.m_aList << "===B===\n" << result.m_bList << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
===A===
0
2
3
===B===
7531
246
```

Adding another qi::symbols element into the structure, the newly added element is expected to be parsed as FRUIT::APPLE (0), but it is actually *indeterminate* (appearing random).

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

typedef std::vector<unsigned int> uint_vector_t;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const uint_vector_t &data)
{
    for (unsigned int i(0); i < data.size(); i++)
    {
        out << data[i] << '\n';
    }
    return out;
}

struct MyStruct
{
    enum class  FRUIT
    {
        APPLE,
        BANANA,
        PEAR,
    } fruit;
    uint_vector_t m_aList;
    uint_vector_t m_bList;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT
(
    MyStruct,
    (MyStruct::FRUIT, fruit)
    (uint_vector_t, m_aList)
    (uint_vector_t, m_bList)
)


template<typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
struct MyParser : public boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator,
        MyStruct(),Skipper>
{
    MyParser() :
        MyParser::base_type(Parser, "Parser")
    {
        using boost::spirit::qi::uint_;
        using boost::spirit::qi::_val;
            using boost::spirit::qi::_1;

        using boost::phoenix::at_c;
        using boost::phoenix::push_back;
        using boost::phoenix::bind;

        fruiter.add
                ("apple",   MyStruct::FRUIT::APPLE)
                ("banana",  MyStruct::FRUIT::BANANA)
                ("pear",    MyStruct::FRUIT::PEAR)
                ;

        aParser = "a=" >> uint_;
        bParser = "b=" >> uint_;

        Parser = fruiter >>
           *(  aParser [push_back(bind(&MyStruct::m_aList, _val), _1)]
            |  bParser [push_back(bind(&MyStruct::m_bList, _val), _1)]
            );
    }
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, MyStruct(), Skipper> Parser;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, unsigned int(), Skipper> aParser, bParser;
    boost::spirit::qi::symbols<char, MyStruct::FRUIT>                   fruiter;
};

int main()
{
    using boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse;

    std::string input("apple\na=0\nb=7531\na=2\na=3\nb=246\n");
    std::string::const_iterator begin = input.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = input.end();
    MyParser<std::string::const_iterator, qi::space_type> parser;

    MyStruct result;
    bool succes = qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, parser,qi::space,result);
    assert(succes);

    std::cout << "Fruit: " << int(result.fruit) << "\n===A===\n" <<result.m_aList << "===B===\n" << result.m_bList << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The resulting qi::symbols element is random instead of 0. An example output looks like

```
Fruit: 29899839
===A===
0
2
3
===B===
7531
246
```

However the qi::symbols element itself only works fine, too.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;


struct MyStruct
{
    enum class  FRUIT
    {
        APPLE,
        BANANA,
        PEAR,
    } fruit;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT
(
    MyStruct,
    (MyStruct::FRUIT, fruit)
)


template<typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
struct MyParser : public boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator,
        MyStruct(),Skipper>
{
    MyParser() :
        MyParser::base_type(Parser, "Parser")
    {
        using boost::spirit::qi::uint_;
        using boost::spirit::qi::_val;
            using boost::spirit::qi::_1;

        using boost::phoenix::at_c;
        using boost::phoenix::push_back;
        using boost::phoenix::bind;

        fruiter.add
                ("apple",   MyStruct::FRUIT::APPLE)
                ("banana",  MyStruct::FRUIT::BANANA)
                ("pear",    MyStruct::FRUIT::PEAR)
                ;

        Parser = fruiter;
    }
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, MyStruct(), Skipper> Parser;
    boost::spirit::qi::symbols<char, MyStruct::FRUIT>                   fruiter;
};

int main()
{
    using boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse;

    std::string input("apple");
    std::string::const_iterator begin = input.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = input.end();
    MyParser<std::string::const_iterator, qi::space_type> parser;

    MyStruct result;
    bool succes = qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, parser,qi::space,result);
    assert(succes);

    std::cout << "Fruit: " << int(result.fruit) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The result looks like:

```
Fruit: 0
```

What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you not use ranged-for in c++14

Comment: @sehe: That piece of code was copied from online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantic actions inhibit automatic propagation of attributes. This is obviously also the reason why the first version of the program didn't nead any for of adaptation for the `MyResult` struct.

So either

1. Stick to semantic actions¹ (dropping adapt-struct)

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fee9b14cc3286dd)</kbd>**

   ```
       Parser = fruiter[bind(&MyStruct::fruit, _val) = _1] >> 
           *( aParser [push_back(bind(&MyStruct::m_aList, _val), _1)] 
           |  bParser [push_back(bind(&MyStruct::m_bList, _val), _1)]
           );
   ```
2. Or use [`operator%=`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/non_terminals.html) to re-enable automatic attribute propagation semantics.

   ```
   // NOTE c++11+ syntax:
   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(MyStruct, fruit, m_aList, m_bList)

   Parser %= fruiter >> 
       *( aParser [push_back(bind(&MyStruct::m_aList, _val), _1)] 
       |  bParser [push_back(bind(&MyStruct::m_bList, _val), _1)]
       );
   ```

   Note that this could easily break down had `fruit` not been the first adapted sequence element. In fact, it's much cleaner to only adapt the expected element:

   ```
   BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(MyStruct, fruit)
   ```

   Even cleaner to make explicit which attributes are expected to propagate:

   ```
   Parser %= fruiter >> 
       omit [
          *( aParser [push_back(bind(&MyStruct::m_aList, _val), _1)] 
           | bParser [push_back(bind(&MyStruct::m_bList, _val), _1)]
           )
       ];
   ```

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1143d1fbf37dca87)</kbd>**

### Full Listing

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1143d1fbf37dca87)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

typedef std::vector<unsigned int> Uints;

namespace std {
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Uints &data) {
        for (auto i : data) out << i << " ";
        return out << "\n";
    }
}

struct MyStruct {
    enum class FRUIT {
        APPLE,
        BANANA,
        PEAR,
    } fruit;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, FRUIT f) {
        switch(f) {
            case FRUIT::APPLE:  return out << "APPLE";
            case FRUIT::BANANA: return out << "BANANA";
            case FRUIT::PEAR:   return out << "PEAR";
        }
        return out << "FRUIT[?" << static_cast<int>(f) << "]";
    }
    Uints m_aList;
    Uints m_bList;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(MyStruct, fruit)

template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper>
struct MyParser : public qi::grammar<Iterator, MyStruct(), Skipper> {
    MyParser() : MyParser::base_type(Parser, "Parser") {
        using namespace qi;
        using boost::phoenix::push_back;
        using boost::phoenix::bind;

        fruiter.add("apple", MyStruct::FRUIT::APPLE)("banana", MyStruct::FRUIT::BANANA)("pear", MyStruct::FRUIT::PEAR);

        aParser = "a=" >> uint_;
        bParser = "b=" >> uint_;

        Parser %= fruiter >> 
            omit [
               *( aParser [push_back(bind(&MyStruct::m_aList, _val), _1)] 
                | bParser [push_back(bind(&MyStruct::m_bList, _val), _1)]
                )
            ];
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, MyStruct(), Skipper> Parser;
    qi::rule<Iterator, unsigned int(), Skipper> aParser, bParser;
    qi::symbols<char, MyStruct::FRUIT> fruiter;
};

int main() {
    std::string input("banana\na=0\nb=7531\na=2\na=3\nb=246\n");
    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    It begin = input.begin(), end = input.end();
    MyParser<It, qi::space_type> parser;

    MyStruct result;
    bool succes = qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, parser, qi::space, result);

    if (succes) {
        std::cout 
            << "Fruit: " << result.fruit 
            << "\n===A===\n" <<result.m_aList << "===B===\n" << result.m_bList << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Fruit: BANANA
===A===
0 2 3 
===B===
7531 246
```

¹ repeating my mantra: [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)

Comment: Thanks a lot, sehe. I will follow your suggestion on "only adapt the expected element", which makes my program so much cleaner. Also thanks for the tip on C++11+ syntax.